# VB - Assigning Strings in an Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to assign values to the strings in a comma separated string.
See incorrect code below.

```
Dim newArray As String() = "M2-1_,IR,Pass,499V,>10G,5.0s"
results = Split(newArray, ",", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
Dim results1 As String = newArray(0)
Dim results2 As String = newArray(1)
Dim results3 As String = newArray(2)
ListBox1.Items.Add(results1)
ListBox1.Items.Add(results2)
ListBox1.Items.Add(results3)
```

My current results are:

```
M    
2    
-
```

I would like the results:

```
M2-1_
IR
Pass
```

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the first 3:

```
    Dim newArray As String = "M2 - 1_,IR,Pass,499V,>10G,5.0s"
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(newArray.Split(",").Take(3).ToArray)
```

If you want them all:

```
    Dim newArray As String = "M2 - 1_,IR,Pass,499V,>10G,5.0s"
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(newArray.Split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim newArray = "M2-1_,IR,Pass,499V,>10G,5.0s"
  Dim results() As String = newArray.Split(",")
  ListBox1.Items.Add(results1(0))
  ListBox1.Items.Add(results2(1))
  ListBox1.Items.Add(results3(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you index into the `results` array when adding to the ListBox.

```
Dim newArray As String = "M2-1_,IR,Pass,499V,>10G,5.0s"
Dim results() = Split(newArray, ",", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
ListBox1.Items.Add(results(0))
ListBox1.Items.Add(results(1))
ListBox1.Items.Add(results(2))
```